# Para que serve o arquivo content_main.xml?

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou começando a estudar Android, utilizando a ferramenta Android Studio e estou com um problema: por mais que eu pesquise livros ou video-aulas nunca acho uma que esteja atualizada.

Estou com a versão 1.5.1, e na criação de um projeto são criados dois arquivos XML na pasta layout, um chamado `content_main.xml` e outro chamado `activity_main.xml`

Nos lugares onde vejo não mostra a criação do arquivo `content_main.xml`. Para que ele serve? Por que houve essa mudança?

Comment: Se você gosta de livros, entende inglês e tem condições financeiras para tal, o [The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development](https://commonsware.com/Android/) é um bom recurso no quesito estar sempre atualizado.

Comment: Muito caro.. Sugere algum site onde eu possa pegar coisas atualizadas e de graça ou algum livro em conta?

Comment: Fique sempre ligada no site oficial de desenvolvedores Android mesmo. Vá por partes: aprenda o que existia até o Android 2.3 (Activity, Service, BroadcastReceiver, Notification), depois dê uma estudada boa na Support Library v4 e na AppCompat v7 e em Fragments. Depois disso, vá para o Material Design, depois para as permissões do Android 6.0. A partir daí, fique sempre ligada nos novos lançamentos do Android e da Support Library pelo próprio site do Android mesmo. O problema é que você chegou tarde-- o sistema evolui rápido. Mas novidades grandes saem uma vez por ano. Dá pra acompanhar.

Comment: Essa questão do content.xml é coisa da API 23-- coisa nova. Não vou arriscar uma resposta porque não mexi ainda, mas a questão é que agora é recomendado separar elementos visuais (botões, campos de texto) de elementos estruturais (sliders, abas). Os elementos visuais devem ir no content_main.xml e os outros vão no activity_main.xml .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a content_main se refere ao conteúdo da sua Activity,é la onde você vai editar o corpo da sua Activity(colocar botões,switchs,etc),e o Activity_main é o layout propriamente dito,é onde você edita o widget e background(fundo) da sua Activity

Nota:Eu não posso dizer que sou um especialista no assunto(na verdade eu sou muito noob),mais se você for trabalhar com isso,eu recomendo que você dê uma lixada no seu java e também no seu xml,acompanhe as atualizações e sempre leia as funções e os pacotes do android que você pode ultilizar no site deles http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/packages.html

la tem tudo que você precisa praticamente para manusear seu app(como eu disse nao sou um especialista),mais se você está começando é uma boa